# Add Custom Route name with custom action name in WebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I have my `WebApiController` with name AdminDashBoard.

```
 public class AdminDashBoardController : ApiController
 {
        [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]       
        public HttpResponseMessage GetCaseHistory(string CaseRefId, string token)
        {
           **Implementation**
        }
 }
```

I am able to access API using 
`Localhost/api/AdminDashBoard/GetCaseHistory?CaseRefId=CTcs004&token=eygk`

But i want to access this by custom name such as
`Localhost/api/Cases/GetCaseHistory?CaseRefId=CTcs004&token=eygk`

I have defined customroutes in my `WebApiConfig` but it is not working.

`config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("CaseHistory", "api/cases/{action}/{CaseRefId}/{token}", defaults: new { controller = "AdminDashBoard", action = "GetCaseHistory", CaseRefId = RouteParameter.Optional, token = RouteParameter.Optional });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the routing you configured will resolve to:

```
controller => AdminDashBoard
action => GetCaseHistory
```

But please note that since you've placed /{action} in rout template string, it will affect detection of routing to expect an "action" specified in request URL.

could you try this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("CaseHistory",
            "api/Cases/GetCaseHistory", 
            defaults: 
              new { controller = "AdminDashBoard", 
                    action = "GetCaseHistory" });
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

remember to place your route before default route as default route will capture the request before the customized one.

In addition, you don't need to define parameters "CaseRefId" and "token" in query string into routing, it should be resolved if you have defined correct type in controller method.

Hope this helps.